# How to filter xml data according to the search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

```
<pages>
    <link>
        <title>HTML a tag</title>
        <url>http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp</url>
    </link>
    <link>
        <title>HTML br tag</title>
        <url>http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp</url>
    </link>
    <link>
        <title>CSS background Property</title>
        <url>http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp</url>
    </link>
    <link>
        <title>CSS border Property</title>
        <url>http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp</url>
    </link>
    <link>
        <title>JavaScript Date Object</title>
        <url>http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp</url>
    </link>
    <link>
        <title>JavaScript Array Object</title>
        <url>http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp</url>
    </link>
</pages>
```

this is the sample xml data which i am parsing and getting the output from

**SEARCH.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link  
href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myArr = [];

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost/category/links.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: parseXml,
            complete: setupAC,
            failure: function (data) {
                alert("XML File could not be found");
            }
        });

        function parseXml(xml) {
            //find every query value
            $(xml).find("link").each(function () {
                myArr.push($(this).find('title').text());
            });
        }

        function setupAC() {
            $("input#searchBox").autocomplete({
                source: myArr,
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    $("input#searchBox").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#searchForm").submit();
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
</head>

    <body style="font-size: 62.5%;">

        <form name="search_form" id="searchForm" method="GET" action="http://localhost/search_result1.html">
            <label for="searchBox">Keyword Search</label>
            <input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchString" />

            <button name="searchKeyword" id="searchKeyword">Sumbit</button>
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

and this my search bar with auto complete feature. In it i first parse the above xml and then store the title in an array which i can use it for auto completeion feature. and on clicking the submit i redirect the page to another html page where i show all the results.

the code for the second html page is as given below..

**RESULT.HTML**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="1.7.2.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dvContent").append("<div></div>");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/category/link.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('link').each(function () {
                        var stitle = $(this).find('title').text();
                        var surl = $(this).find('url').text();
                        $("<li></li>").html(stitle + ", " + surl).appendTo("#dvContent div");
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="dvContent">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but what i want is to show only the title and url of the searched term. In this i am getting the entire xml as output. So in there a way by which i can show only the title and url of the searched term.

that is i get the output in result.html as

```
 . HTML a tag, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp
 . HTML br tag, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp
```

on searching for the term HTML in the search in search.html

Comment: I can't see where are you getting the value from the search form input in the results.html page. If you want to filter the results you are going to need this value and filter from the source xml using it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <script src="1.7.2.jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#dvContent").append("<div></div>");
            var searchValue = $('#searchBox').val();  // Here you get the search text
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://localhost/category/link.xml",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function (xml) {
                    $(xml).find('link').each(function () {
                        var stitle = $(this).find('title').text();
                        var surl = $(this).find('url').text();
                        if (searchValue === stitle) {  // Only append those if search text matches with title
                            $("<li></li>").html(stitle + ", " + surl).appendTo("#dvContent div");
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="dvContent">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but i am not able to get the **searchValue**..It is coming as undefined

Comment: there is no error at all..So i tried giving an alert and checking the value stored in  the searchValue and the alert returned undefined

Comment: @Stephen Rodriguez which mean there is nothing in `<input type="text" id="searchBox" name="searchString" />`

Comment: @Stephen Rodriguez write `HTML a tag` in `input field` then search

Comment: i am using two different htmls..in one i enter the search and on submitting i am redircted to the result page where i will be shown the result for the search...